# Apache mod-rewrite in httpd.conf not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, iphone, apache-config

I need to make a change to my Apache web server to redirect requests for the home page from iPhone browsers to a different page. I've edited the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and added the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*iPhone.*
RewriteRule ^/$ /iphone/index.html [L]
```

After making the change, I restarted httpd, but the redirect doesn't work.

Am I missing something? Do the edits need to be made to a specific location in the httpd.conf file?

Other info: Server is vps hosted by Lunarpages running CentOS 5.5 and Apache 2.2.3.

Comment: Do you know exactly what your HTTP_USER_AGENT string looks like when you browse your site?

Comment: @peter I've used this to access iPhone specific pages of other sites :  Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3

Comment: Are you saying that you have configured Mozilla/5.0 to send the string "User-Agent: iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en" in the header of the HTTP request, or is that what Mozilla running on an iPhone looks like? What I'm wondering specifically is what your Apache instance is seeing when it handles the request. One way to get a lot of useful information about what Apache is actually doing when URL rewriting is turned on is to turn on RewriteLog (and RewriteLogLevel) - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Thanks @peter, I'll try switching on logging, but can you tell me if what I've done so far is correct? I used that user agent string with Safari in Mac OS X 10.7. If you show the Develop menu (from Safari Perferences) you can specify a specific User Agent, and I manually entered the string (originally obtained from http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iphone-user-agent/)

Comment: @peter, I set up the log with a RewriteLogLevel 2 but it isn't recording any information. I'm guessing this means the Rewrite engine isn't doing any work. This is one of the entries in the web server log "24.5.98.147 - - [25/Jul/2011:12:18:01 -0700] "GET /rw_common/themes/dexture/images/editable_images/concrete.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://petersonguides.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533."

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your RewriteCond and your RewriteRule (though you should be able to drop the .* stuff from the RewriteCond, as patterns are not left or right "anchored" by default). If you kick RewriteLogLevel up to 9 and still don't see anything then you know mod_rewrite is *definitely* not being engaged - in which case you'll need some other way to verify that you're tweaking the correct httpd.conf file.

Comment: OK, I fixed the problem. There's a <VirtualHost xxx> section in the httpd.conf file and I copied my rewrite rules inside the section. Works like a charm. Thanks for your help @peter. The log helped me diagnose and fix the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. At this point I guess you can answer your own question, accept the answer, and resolve the question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use like below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*iPhone.*
RewriteRule ^[\./]$ <MyDomain>/iphone/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I resolved the problem by moving therewrite rule inside the <VirtualHosts xxx> tag in the httpd.comf file.